# sudo apt-get update error warning

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the errors and warnings below:

(updated after trying Norbert's solution)

```
Reading package lists... Done
 W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
 W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
```

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list (updated):

[image: sources.list screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix several issues:

1. `... is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54` - by manual editing of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and commenting out duplicate 54 line.
2. manually remove packages lists:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   ```
3. disable PPAs without Xenial packages:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:picaso/octave
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:samuellb/fribid
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:tomahawk/ppa
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:yorba/ppa
   ```
4. add fresh [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/int/download/linux/) GPG key:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 931FF8E79F0876134EDDBDCCA87FF9DF48BF1C90
   ```
5. update package lists

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
6. install all upgrades

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Comment: When i exceute the step 2 line it says:sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*

rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory

Comment: Then try with recursive flag -  `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the recent warnings and my sources.list image , I'm still getting those warnings ,the errors are fixed

Comment: Carefully compare lines 51 and 54 inside */etc/apt/sources.list* and comment out one of them.